# Filtering a list of strings in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

For an assignment I have to filter a list without using the built-in function in Python. Here's my code :

```
def satisfiesF(L):
    result = 0
    i = 0
    L1 = []
    while i < len(L):
        s = L[i]
        if f(s) == True :
            result += 1
            L1.append(L[i])
        i += 1
    L = L1
    print L
    return result
def f(s):
    return 'a' in s
L = ['a', 'b', 'a']
print satisfiesF(L)
print L
```

It prints :

```
['a', 'a']
2
['a', 'b', 'a']
```

Why is the second L not the same as the first? I have searched for hours but I can't understand. It seems to me that here L is passed by reference so why doesn't the value change?

I've tried changing the line `L = L1` in `L = list(L1)` but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
L = L1
```

This makes `L` reference to the list that `L1` references. Add `print(id(L))` before and after this line, you could see its `id` has changed.

One way to keep `L` the same `id` while getting the content of `L1` is to clear it first and then append:

```
del L[:]
L.append(L1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple mistake of the scope of local and global variables.

Inside your function `satisfiesF(L)` the line

```
L = L1
```

changes the `L` which is declared inside the function which you passed to the function `satisfiesF()` as an argument. You could have passed `L'` and tried printing `L'`, it would work just fine. But `print L` would give `variable out of scope` error.

But when you do

```
print L
```

in the last line, it will print the `L` declared just two lines above it as `L = ['a', 'b', 'a']`

Comment: I understand that but how do I avoid that? How do I change L? I just found that "All parameters (arguments) in the Python language are passed by reference. It means if you change what a parameter refers to within a function, the change also reflects back in the calling function" (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)

Comment: You can change L by declaring it on the top level (you've done) and passing a different name to your function, say `L'` and change the value of L from inside the function will do the job.

Comment: Or you simply don't need to pass any argument as it's declared globally.

Comment: I have to pass it as an argument, I can't change the signature.  I don't understand what you meant in your second comment. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: You can simply define your function as `def satisfiesF():` as you are changing the variable from the global scope.

Comment: I can't change the signature, it was given to me for an assignment. That's my problem

Answer (score 0):

As Himanshu points out, the scope is the issue. That is why this works, since it sets `self.L`

```
class my_test:
    def __init__(self, values, check):
        self.L = values
        self.check = check

    def run_test(self):
        print self.satisfiesF()
        print self.L

    def f(self, s):
        return self.check in s

    def satisfiesF(self):
        result = 0
        i = 0
        L1 = []
        while i < len(self.L):
            s = self.L[i]
            if self.f(s) == True :
                result += 1
                L1.append(self.L[i])
            i += 1
        self.L = L1
        print self.L
        return result

x = my_test(['a', 'b', 'a'], 'a')
x.run_test()
```

Output is

```
['a', 'a']
2
['a', 'a']
```

Comment: I understand what you did but it doesn't help me because like I said I have to do this as part of an assignment and I can only modify satisfiesF not the rest and when I try your code I have an error that says : 'list' object has no attribute 'L'

Comment: In the Q it sounded like you wrote the function, and weren't modifying/reparing an existing one. Not sure why you got an error, I didn't have it. You could always return `L` instead of `result`, or return `[L, result]` and then sort it out